# Maven: missing artifact presto

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, presto

I want add a new dependency into pom.xml. The eclipse shows the error: "Missing artifact presto:presto-jdbc:jar: 0.93" 
I have tried to force update of snapshot. No fix.

```
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.29</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>presto</groupId>
        <artifactId>presto-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>0.93</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Are groupId, artifactId named arbitrarily? How can I fix this problem?(
No update dependency in Maven in my eclipse.)

Comment: Try using the entry given here - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.presto/presto-jdbc/0.93

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at maven central your dependency should be

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.facebook.presto</groupId>
    <artifactId>presto-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>0.93</version>
</dependency>
```

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.facebook.presto%7Cpresto-jdbc%7C0.93%7Cjar